# How to convert SVG Path (SVGOMPathElement) to array of points?

Tags: java, svg, element, shapes, batik

What I'm trying to do: convert an SVG path to an array of (x,y) points.

I have this at the moment:

```
public Point[] strokeToPoints(Node n){

    SVGOMPathElement path = (SVGOMPathElement) n;

    System.out.println(path.getAttribute("d")); 

    System.out.println(path.getTotalLength());

    return null;

}
```

Node n is always a path element extracted from an SVG file which looks something like this:

`<path id="kvg:098df-s1" kvg:type="㇒" d="M52.75,10.5c0.11,0.98-0.19,2.67-0.97,3.93C45,25.34,31.75,41.19,14,51.5"/>`

The line

```
System.out.println(path.getAttribute("d"));
```

returns

```
M52.75,10.5c0.11,0.98-0.19,2.67-0.97,3.93C45,25.34,31.75,41.19,14,51.5
```

which is fine, but the line

```
System.out.println(path.getTotalLength());
```

returns

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGPathSupport.getTotalLength(SVGPathSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMPathElement.getTotalLength(SVGOMPathElement.java:131)
```

What's causing this error? I need the total length so I can traverse it collecting the points to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be something like:

```
PathLength  pathLenObj = new PathLength((Shape) n);
float  length = pathLenObj.pathLength;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed your suggestion but unfortunately received the error: org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMPathElement cannot be cast to java.awt.Shape
Could you possibly cast any further light on the situation?

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  I didn't check the definition of Shape.  It looks like it may be an internal class that is not intended for users to use.  Maybe you'll have better luck getting help on the Batik mailing list. http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/mailing-lists.html

Comment: I'll do that. I made what I thought was some progress to my problem but have hit another road block. I've revised my question. I'd be grateful if you would be so kind as to take a look.